# Google Spreadsheet -How to count unique values based on 2 columns with criteria from other columns?

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet, array-formulas

I  have the following data:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/16JyE91jVJ8CgLfBhlygQCA85xJs5cjQLojM6b318JNQ/edit#gid=0

In a single cell, I want to get the number of unique Countries & Cities with Status = "PENDING" and Special Package  = "Yes" with out creating a new column. I tried using the following formula:

```
=COUNTUNIQUEIFS(ARRAYFORMULA(A2:A&B2:B),D2:D,"PENDING",E2:E,"Yes")
```

But it returns the error: Argument must be a range.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use it like this:

```
=COUNTUNIQUEIFS(A2:A7,D2:D7 ,"PENDING", E2:E7, "Yes")
```

So you are saying:

```
Count from A column
Where D column = "PENDING"
And E column = "YES"
```

Check [COUNTUNIQUEIF](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/9584429?hl=en) documentation.

---

**Update**

You can count the uniques with the B column since the countries will repeat in almost any circumstance, so you can count the unique cities that have the conditions.

Also you can use a query to group the results by country or city and even show you which one is:

`=QUERY(A2:E7, "select count(B), B, A where D ='PENDING' and E ='Yes' GROUP BY A,B")`

[image]

Comment: Is there a work arround where I can use both Columns A & B as reference?